# Stop Live Messenger From Syncing Window Status Between Computers

Tags: windows-live-messenger, instant-messaging, chat, windows-live

Okay, so a minor annoyance has started to become a really bad annoyance lately. If I have WLM (v 15.4 right now) open on multiple computers (or on my phone, through Trillian), and close a conversation window on one computer, it automatically closes the window on all my signed in computers. Is there a way to keep this from happening? I couldn't find anything in the settings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could of sworn there is a setting like about "multiple places" under WLM.  I don't have WLM on this computer to check.

Actually, second hit on Google

http://forum.thewindowsclub.com/windows-tips-tutorials-articles/27648-how-turn-off-sign-multiple-feature-wlm.html

Comment: Thanks surfasb. It's not that I want to disable multiple sign-in, I just want to keep it from modifying windows on one machine based on my actions on another machine. e.g. if I close a chat window on my phone, it should stay open on my desktop.